# Octane SDK (impinj RFID reader) fails to save settings

Tags: java, kotlin, rfid

I got Speedway R420 RFID reader. Trying to read tags. It does work on a real model connected to emulator or real Android device, but during field test it fails. Studying logs I managed to clarify that it fails during simple enough operation. Here's draft code:

```
val reader = ImpinjReader()
reader.name = "ATZ Reader"
reader.connectTimeout = 60000
reader.connect(readerHostname) //10.1.30.172
reader.setKeepaliveListener { impinjReader, keepaliveEvent ->
            Timber.d("Keepalive received from %s, %s, %s",
             impinjReader.name, impinjReader.address, keepaliveEvent)
            _connectStatus.tryEmit(RfIdStatus.Success)
}
reader.setConnectionLostListener {
            if(!it.isConnected) {
                logger.logRFID("Los connection ${it.name}, ${it.address}")
                _connectStatus.tryEmit(RfIdStatus.Disconnected)
            }
            else
                _connectStatus.tryEmit(RfIdStatus.Success)
        }
reader.tagReportListener = tagReportListener
val settings = reader.queryDefaultSettings()
reader.applySettings(settings) //Exception thrown at this line
reader.saveSettings()
reader.start()
CoroutineScope(newSingleThreadContext("rfid reader")).launch {
            while (true) {
                delay(10000)
                try {
                    reader.queryTags()
                    _connectStatus.emit(RfIdStatus.Success)
                    logger.logRFID("Tags queried")
                } catch (e: OctaneSdkException) {
                    logger.logRFID("Tags query error ${e.message}")
                    reader.disconnect()
                    break
                }
            }
}
```

Here's stacktrace:

```
OctaneSdk exception: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<llrp:ADD_ROSPEC_RESPONSE xmlns:llrp="http://www.llrp.org/ltk/schema/core/encoding/xml/1.0" xmlns:Impinj="http://developer.impinj.com/ltk/schema/encoding/xml/1.46" Version="1" MessageID="5">
  <llrp:LLRPStatus>
    <llrp:StatusCode>M_FieldError</llrp:StatusCode>
    <llrp:ErrorDescription>LLRP [420] : //C1G2RFControl/ModeIndex : out-of-range</llrp:ErrorDescription>
    <llrp:ParameterError>
      <llrp:ParameterType>177</llrp:ParameterType>
      <llrp:ErrorCode>P_ParameterError</llrp:ErrorCode>
      <llrp:ParameterError>
        <llrp:ParameterType>183</llrp:ParameterType>
        <llrp:ErrorCode>P_ParameterError</llrp:ErrorCode>
        <llrp:ParameterError>
          <llrp:ParameterType>186</llrp:ParameterType>
          <llrp:ErrorCode>P_ParameterError</llrp:ErrorCode>
          <llrp:ParameterError>
            <llrp:ParameterType>222</llrp:ParameterType>
            <llrp:ErrorCode>P_ParameterError</llrp:ErrorCode>
            <llrp:ParameterError>
              <llrp:ParameterType>330</llrp:ParameterType>
              <llrp:ErrorCode>P_ParameterError</llrp:ErrorCode>
              <llrp:ParameterError>
                <llrp:ParameterType>335</llrp:ParameterType>
                <llrp:ErrorCode>P_FieldError</llrp:ErrorCode>
                <llrp:FieldError>
                  <llrp:FieldNum>1</llrp:FieldNum>
                  <llrp:ErrorCode>A_OutOfRange</llrp:ErrorCode>
                </llrp:FieldError>
              </llrp:ParameterError>
            </llrp:ParameterError>
          </llrp:ParameterError>
        </llrp:ParameterError>
      </llrp:ParameterError>
    </llrp:ParameterError>
  </llrp:LLRPStatus>
</llrp:ADD_ROSPEC_RESPONSE>


    at com.impinj.octane.ImpinjReader.addRoSpec(ImpinjReader.java:1220)
    at com.impinj.octane.ImpinjReader.applySettingsWithOptionalFactoryReset(ImpinjReader.java:1050)
    at com.impinj.octane.ImpinjReader.applySettings(ImpinjReader.java:1008)
    at com.impinj.octane.ImpinjReader.applySettings(ImpinjReader.java:1068)
    at ru.avangard.refueler.features.datacollector.service.RfidReaderClient.setVariantA(RfidReaderClient.kt:70)
    at ru.avangard.refueler.features.datacollector.service.RfidReaderClient.start(RfidReaderClient.kt:48)
    at ru.avangard.refueler.features.datacollector.service.DataCollectorService$startRfidReaderClient$1.invokeSuspend(DataCollectorService.kt:131)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
```

Any ideas, hints, clues?

**Update:**

Settings read from device are following:

```
{
  "antennas": {
    "antennaCollectionCreatedBySerializer": false,
    "antennaConfigs": [
      {
        "enabled": true,
        "isMaxRxSensitivity": true,
        "isMaxTxPower": true,
        "portName": "Antenna Port 1",
        "portNumber": 1,
        "rxSensitivityinDbm": 0.0,
        "txPowerinDbm": 0.0
      },
      {
        "enabled": true,
        "isMaxRxSensitivity": true,
        "isMaxTxPower": true,
        "portName": "Antenna Port 2",
        "portNumber": 2,
        "rxSensitivityinDbm": 0.0,
        "txPowerinDbm": 0.0
      },
      {
        "enabled": true,
        "isMaxRxSensitivity": true,
        "isMaxTxPower": true,
        "portName": "Antenna Port 3",
        "portNumber": 3,
        "rxSensitivityinDbm": 0.0,
        "txPowerinDbm": 0.0
      },
      {
        "enabled": true,
        "isMaxRxSensitivity": true,
        "isMaxTxPower": true,
        "portName": "Antenna Port 4",
        "portNumber": 4,
        "rxSensitivityinDbm": 0.0,
        "txPowerinDbm": 0.0
      }
    ],
    "isMaxRxSensitivity": true,
    "isMaxTxPower": true,
    "polarizationEnabled": false,
    "rxSensitivityinDbm": 0.0,
    "txPowerinDbm": 0.0
  },
  "autoStart": {
    "firstDelayInMs": 0,
    "gpiPortNumber": 0,
    "mode": "Immediate",
    "periodInMs": 0,
    "utcTimestamp": 0
  },
  "autoStop": {
    "durationInMs": 0,
    "gpiPortNumber": 0,
    "mode": "None",
    "timeout": 0
  },
  "filters": {
    "Mode": "None",
    "TagFilter1": {
      "BitCount": 0,
      "BitPointer": 0
    },
    "TagFilter2": {
      "BitCount": 0,
      "BitPointer": 0
    },
    "tagSelectFilterList": []
  },
  "gpis": {
    "gpiCollectionCreatedBySerializer": false,
    "gpiConfigs": [
      {
        "debounceInMs": 0,
        "isEnabled": false,
        "portNumber": 1
      },
      {
        "debounceInMs": 0,
        "isEnabled": false,
        "portNumber": 2
      },
      {
        "debounceInMs": 0,
        "isEnabled": false,
        "portNumber": 3
      },
      {
        "debounceInMs": 0,
        "isEnabled": false,
        "portNumber": 4
      }
    ]
  },
  "gpos": {
    "gpoCollectionCreatedBySerializer": false,
    "gpoConfigs": [
      {
        "gpoPulseDurationMsec": 0,
        "mode": "Normal",
        "portNumber": 1
      },
      {
        "gpoPulseDurationMsec": 0,
        "mode": "Normal",
        "portNumber": 2
      },
      {
        "gpoPulseDurationMsec": 0,
        "mode": "Normal",
        "portNumber": 3
      },
      {
        "gpoPulseDurationMsec": 0,
        "mode": "Normal",
        "portNumber": 4
      }
    ]
  },
  "holdReportsOnDisconnect": true,
  "keepalives": {
    "enableLinkMonitorMode": false,
    "enabled": false,
    "linkDownThreshold": 0,
    "periodInMs": 0
  },
  "lowDutyCycle": {
    "EmptyFieldTimeoutInMs": 0,
    "FieldPingIntervalInMs": 0,
    "IsEnabled": false
  },
  "readerMode": "AutoSetDenseReaderDeepScan",
  "reducedPowerFrequenciesInMhz": [],
  "report": {
    "includeAntennaPortNumber": false,
    "includeChannel": false,
    "includeCrc": false,
    "includeDopplerFrequency": false,
    "includeFastId": false,
    "includeFirstSeenTime": true,
    "includeGpsCoordinates": false,
    "includeLastSeenTime": true,
    "includePcBits": false,
    "includePeakRssi": false,
    "includePhaseAngle": false,
    "includeSeenCount": true,
    "mode": "Individual",
    "optimizedReadOps": []
  },
  "searchMode": "DualTarget",
  "session": 2,
  "tagPopulationEstimate": 32,
  "truncatedReply": {
    "bitPointer": 32,
    "epcLengthInWords": 0,
    "gen2v2TagsOnly": false,
    "isEnabled": false,
    "tagMask": ""
  },
  "txFrequenciesInMhz": [],
  "xArray": {
    "spatialConfig": {
      "direction": {
        "diagnosticReportEnabled": false,
        "enabledSectors": [],
        "entryReportEnabled": true,
        "exitReportEnabled": true,
        "fieldOfView": "READER_SELECTED",
        "isMaxTxPower": true,
        "mode": "HighPerformance",
        "tagAgeIntervalSeconds": 2,
        "txPowerinDbm": 0.0,
        "updateIntervalSeconds": 2,
        "updateReportEnabled": true,
        "userTagPopulationLimit": 0
      },
      "location": {
        "computeWindowSeconds": 10,
        "diagnosticReportEnabled": false,
        "disabledAntennaList": [],
        "entryReportEnabled": true,
        "exitReportEnabled": true,
        "isMaxTxPower": true,
        "locationAlgorithmControl": [],
        "tagAgeIntervalSeconds": 20,
        "txPowerinDbm": 0.0,
        "updateIntervalSeconds": 5,
        "updateReportEnabled": true
      },
      "mode": "Inventory",
      "placement": {
        "facilityXLocationCm": 0,
        "facilityYLocationCm": 0,
        "heightCm": 400,
        "orientationDegrees": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: http://llrp.org/docs/javaapidoc/org/llrp/ltk/types/LLRPParameter.html

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see it looks like the ModeIndex for your C1G2RFControl is out of range. The LLRP standard has historically mixed together ModeIndex and ModeIdentifier, which I have found to be confusing at best in some cases very ambiguous direction when  selecting a reader mode. Are you working with a sllurp inventory? If so try --mode-identifier N instead of -mode-index and see if that helps. If you want to find out the the mode designations your specific Impinj reader model supports through the C1G2RFControl option, check the reader's documentation or run sllurp --debug inventory command on the reader to get a dump of the supported modes. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: thanx for your kind reply. I really have no idea about modeindex/modeidentifier, I'm just reading default settings and trying to apply them to reader back. What's wrong with this?

Just added to my original post settings of reader, can you please say what's wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the Impinj OctaneSDK in C# with an RFID project I downloaded from GitHub.

The code was slow to connect to the reader and then threw a null reference exception with reader.ApplySettings. The reader and settings objects looked fully populated.

Like the OP I narrowed it down to simply applying the unchanged settings I had just retrieved from the reader. It still failed.

It turned out that the OctaneSDK.dll (2.0.0.6) and LLRP.dll (10.16.0.240) included with the project were older versions that failed when being applied to a new Impinj R700 reader. Updating to 3.7.0.0 and 10.46.0 respectivly with Nuget fixed the issue.

This project was for .Net 4.62 and 3.7.0.0 is the latest supported version for .Net classic. Octane 4.x is for Net 5/6.

Updating to the last Octane 2.x version that was available made connecting faster, but ApplySettings still threw the Null Reference exception.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, I have managed to fix problem after upgrading Impinj Reader firmware to latest one.